# js && on variable before function call

Tags: javascript, variables, logic, operators, grammar

In the Mozilla Developers Guide on how to write a WebSocket Server in c# I found
this two lines of code in the js client part.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

```
var text = textarea.value;
text && doSend(text);
```

Can somebody tell me, why they would put the var "text" in front of && before the function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a shorthand for

```
if (text) {
  doSend(text);
}
```

If `text` is falsy (null or undefined or an empty string) then the right part will not be executed.

Comment: I see thanks. I also wasn't sure which cases of nullity were supported..

Comment: @Andiroid That's the common 'truthy/falsy' feature. Javascript understands that it needs to boolean values for the `&&` operation and 'converts' `text` into one. See this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for.